# Mathematical expression for $i^{th}$ largest element of a set

Tags: notation, order-statistics, index-notation

Suppose I have a finite set of real numbers $S$, and I want to denote the $i^{th}$ largest element of $S$. Is there a nice mathematical expression to express that value?

Comment: Presumably, you'd write your set as $\{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\}$ where $i < j$ means $x_i > x_j$.  Not really sure how'd you make sense of this for something "too large" like $[0,1]$ or $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Suppose though that we can't find a labelling of indices that easily to have the property you mentioned. Like we are just given a general set $S$ and it is not known what assignment of indices we could do so that we have $\{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$ where $i<j$ means $x_i > x_j$

Comment: Why not?  You're in the real line:  it's already ordered for you.  The only problem would be infinite sets.

Comment: If I have the set $\{4, 1, 3\}$ it's pretty clear that I'll make $x_1=4$, $x_2=3$, and $x_3=1$.

Comment: Yes, but you are assuming a specific example. I mean we don't know necessarily the exact numbers in that set. The first thing you did with the $x_i$'s IS a labelling. We can't assume that we have that. In effect we would want to create such a labelling using a mathematical expression.

Comment: Sure you can.  Let $S$ be a finite set of reals, say $|S|=n$.   Name the elements of $S$ as $x_i$ where $x_1 > x_2> \cdots > x_n$.  Done.

Comment: To illustrate, suppose that I asked "what is a mathematical way to denote the largest element of a set of numbers".  The answer would be to use the notation $\max\limits_{x\in S} x$. Your reply would be the equivalent to saying, just label them 1 through n and pick n. It isn't really a mathematical expression. You see what I'm saying?

Comment: Right, which is completely correct.  Not sure what you want.  I guess you could define an operator $i-\mathrm{max}$ which picks out the $i$th largest number, but guess what?  In order to define that you would first write your set as $S=\{x_1 > x_2 > \cdots > x_n\}$.  Then $i-\mathrm{max}(S)= x_i$.

Comment: You might not need to. For instance, in defining $\max_{x\in S} x$ we did not need to define $x_1, \dots, x_n$. We just simply wrote $\max_{x\in S} x$

Comment: What's wrong with "the $i$-th largest element of $S$"?

Comment: Right:  using language is usually the best way.  Not everything has to be symbolized.

Comment: There is no established notation to the best of my knowledge. But nothing prevents you from introducing your own if you need it.

Comment: "the $i$th largest element of S" is a very nice mathematical way to express the value. .... As is saying "I will use the notation $\mathbb L_k$ to mean the $k$th largest value of the set".  Or we can say "as $S$ is a finite we can order the set and label the elements as $y_1,y_2,..... y_n$ with the condition that $y_1 > y_2 > .... >y_n$.  Now take $y_i$...."

Comment: The reason is that it would be kind of cumbersome in my case, because $S$ is not a notation we have for our set. It would end up being like "the i-th largest element of the set of ... which is the set of...". Now, I could define intermediary sets, but I'm trying to limit my notation.

Comment: "Not everything has to be symbolized." And everyone is allowed to symbolize things anyway they want so long as they explain themselves.  Nothing wrong with using $\mathbb L_k$ (or whatever notation you want) and telling people what you mean.

Comment: Okay.... the answer is "no".  There is not a universally recognized (or more importantly universally *known*) notation for the $k$th largest element of a set.  There hasn't been enough of a need for any notation that anyone has come up with (and I'm sure many individuals *have* temporarily come up with their own-- *I* just came up with one; you are free to use $\mathbb L_k$ if you like) to have been universally adopted.  (I'm not expecting any great rush to have $\mathbb L_k$ adopted.)

Comment: Alrighty thenn.

Comment: The thing is none of us want to say "No, there isn't" as it's quite likely there *is* one that someone is going to claim is *the* way of doing it.  So maybe there is one and I just don't know it.  But I'd say if many mathematicians don't *know* the notation it's not helpful even if it *does* exist and even if it *is* the "official" way of doing it.

Comment: In probability theory, the $i$th *smallest* random variable among $\{X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n\}$ is denoted $X_{(i)}$.  In particular, $X_{(1)} = \min_i X_i$ and $X_{(n)} = \max_i X_i$.